# scipy.optimize.minimize changes values at low decimal place

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

this is my code for the optimisation.

```
  initialGuess = D.Matrix[:,D.menge]
  bnds = D.Matrix[:,(D.mengenMin,D.mengenMax)]
  con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': PercentSum} 
  con2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': MinMaxProportion}
  cons = ([con1,con2])

  solution = minimize(rootfunc,initialGuess,method='SLSQP',\
                bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
```

The Problem is, the algorithm changes values at low decimal place. 
e.g. this is my initial guess. I already tried to change from float to integers, to have a work around.

```
 [  0.   0. 123.   0.   0. 622. 245.   0.   0.   0.]
```

The first try of the of the optimizer looks like this:

```
[1.49011612e-08 0.00000000e+00 1.23000000e+02 0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00 6.22000000e+02 2.45000000e+02 0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
```

Another is this:

```
[  0.           0.         123.00000001   0.           0.
 622.         245.           0.           0.           0.        ]
```

An finally the optimization finishes with this error:

```
status 6
message Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem
```

I think the problem is the tiny difference. Is there a possibility to tell the SLSQP algorithm only to try changes on the first two decimal places or higher?

kind regards

edit: I have found an option, but it does not solve my problem. The new call of scipy.optimize.minimize:

```
solution = minimize(rootfunc,initialGuess,method='SLSQP',\
                bounds=bnds,constraints=con2,options={'eps':1,'disp':True})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those "tiny steps" are not values selected by the solver in each iteration, they are from finite differencing. Gradient-based solvers like this one require gradients. Since you didn't provide the gradients as functions, it defaults to calculating them for you with finite difference. Your real problem, as the error stated, is most likely a singular matrix.